# Creating schema for a shop that sells items from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, schema

I am trying to create a table in mySQl that contains a list of all the items that a shops. For example:

**shops** (shop_ID (PK), shop_name)

**shops_and_items** (shop_ID (PK), item_ID (PK), price)

The issue I'm facing is that a shop can sell two types of products. For example, furniture and clothing. In my database, I already have separate tables for both furniture items and clothing items. The suggested `shops_and_items` schema therefore does not work.

I'm wondering, what is the best way to go about it. Should I create two tables **shop_and_furniture_items** and **shop_and_clothing_items** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend reading the following link on Database Inheritance: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/09/30/how-to-model-inheritance-in-databases.aspx

Databases don't naturally fit hierarchies - they do work, but it's not their strong suit.

In your case I would change **shops_and_items** for

```
**products**(product_id (PK), shop_ID (FK), ... then columns for common fields: name, price, stock, delivery time)
```

Then...

### Option 1 :: Fewer Product Categories

If you only intend to have furniture and clothing then you could do

```
**clothes**(product_ID(FK and PK), size, colour, gender etc)
**furniture**(product_ID(FK and PK), height, width, depth, material etc)
```

Note that product_ID is a foreign key and primary key... a product would either have a corresponding record in clothes OR furniture. This doesn't need to be auto incrementing. A product has one clothes item or one furniture item (not both).

### Option 2 :: Many Product Categories

If you intend to expand to lots of different products (electrical, food, ) and possibly sub-products then you will have a lot of tables and it will be a mess to manage! In this case it's easier to go down a meta-data route like WordPress http://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/9e/WP3.0-ERD.png

WordPress uses wp_posts for a post, page, any many other plugin-defined types (map, questionnaire, gallery etc), if they need extra properties then they are stored in wp_postmeta.

You would keep the products table but add on:

```
**product_meta**(product_id(FK), meta_name, meta_value)

e.g.
4 (Surfer T-Shirt), colour, white
4, size, Medium
4, gender, male
18 (TV Stand), material, metal
18, height 40cm
18, depth 33cm
18, width 60cm
```

This might need some more validation before the data goes into the database as **meta_value** will most likely be a **varchar** column so you will need to standardise how you interpret values. Will your code use M/F for Male/Female? What units for measurments?

**I recommend grabbing some open source shopping carts and installing them just to find out how they structure their SQL code - they will have their own solutions for sub-categories and custom properties of products.**